# Kendo validator not working on text change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-validator

I am using kendo controls for my project. I was using jquery validation to validate my controls at client side but as jquery validation is not working for kendo controls so I am using kendo validators to validate the controls.

I am using dataannotation validation with MVC 5 project. Here is sample [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/axUJiJ).

It is working perfect but the validation only appear on focus-out or blur event. Is there any way to validate control on change of value of control like jquery validation?

**Update:**

Here is the complete solution that helped me to resolve this issue:

```
if ($.validator !== undefined) {
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            ignore: [],
            highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
                element = $(element);
                var highLightElement;
                if (element.parent().hasClass("k-picker-wrap") ||
                    element.parent().hasClass("k-numeric-wrap")) {
                    highLightElement = element.parent().parent();
                }
                else if (element.parent().hasClass("k-widget")) {
                    highLightElement = element.parent();
                } else if (element.parent().children('.k-upload-empty').length > 0) {
                    highLightElement = $(element.parent().children('.k-upload-empty')[0]);
                } else {
                    highLightElement = element;
                }
                highLightElement.addClass('input-validation-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
                element = $(element);
                var highLightElement;
                if (element.parent().hasClass("k-picker-wrap")
                    || element.parent().hasClass("k-numeric-wrap")) {
                    highLightElement = element.parent().parent();
                }
                else if (element.parent().hasClass("k-widget")) {
                    highLightElement = element.parent();
                } else {
                    highLightElement = element;
                }
                highLightElement.removeClass('input-validation-error');
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 ways to meat your purpose:

### Using jQuery Unobtrusive Validation with KendoUI

#### Background

As you know the Kendo UI Editor creates a different elements than HTML form elements. Other JavaScript editors work in a similar fashion. The actual HTML is hidden using CSS (`display: none;`), and therein lies the issue. **By default jQuery Validation ignores hidden input fields**. There are `validation data-*` attributes on the form elements, *but since it is hidden, when the unobtrusive validation fires, the editor is ignored*.

#### Solution

You have 2 ways to solve this issue and perfectly work with both technologies. Read the [Making the Kendo UI Editor Work With jQuery Validations](http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2013/01/14/making-the-kendo-ui-editor-work-with-jquery-validations/) and if you have any problem for implementing, please read [Kendo UI NumericTextBox With jQuery Validation](http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2013/06/27/kendoui-numerictextbox-validation/) as an example for *NumericTextBox*

Then, You may have problem to assign proper CSS class in case of validation. You can read [adding jquery validation to kendo ui elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813868/adding-jquery-validation-to-kendo-ui-elements).

### Just using KendoUI Validators

You should implement desired event for the validation purpose. Here you need `onChange` event to work like jQuery Unobtrusive Validation. Use the following code as it describes what to do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function widgetChange() {
        //place validation logic
    };

    $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: data,
        change: widgetChange
    });
})
```

You may want to **use both of them**! So take a look at [.Net Mvc 3 Trigger (other than submit button) Unobtrusive Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301492/net-mvc-3-trigger-other-than-submit-button-unobtrusive-validation)

#### Update

A [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AbaGa) for implementing with last solution which added a `pattern="\d+"` to *search* input with a validation message. The validation is called by `filtering` event for the same input. **Note that** you should use desired event based on UI element, here we used `filtering` for [autocomplete](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/events) instead of using `change` for [DropDownList](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/events).

I recently found a new implementation which is looking good to try and test. That is available at [aspnet-mvc getting-started validation](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/validation)

Comment: Can you please add dojo or plunker for the implementation?

Comment: @ManpritSinghSahota I added an update to my answer based on your request.

Comment: I have done the same way as mentioned in `https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/validation` but I want that validation should fire when user type something. Also, the border should be red as jquery validation. Currently validation only fires when use press tab key. You can check your dojo as well.

Comment: @ManpritSinghSahota I implemented for a Kendo autocomplete based on your answer, but you can implement for a common `input` element in an easier manner just by writing some js code! In this case, you should change your question, since you need to implement a handy validation for jquery unobtrusive validation. sth like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479255/how-to-manually-trigger-validation-with-jquery-validate

Comment: I tried the link provided by you in the Solution and now I am able to use jquery validation with kendo controls. However it need some more tweaks but its working now. Thanks @Amirhossein Mehrvarzi

Comment: @ManpritSinghSahota I used to work with Telerik controls (including KendoUI). Based on my experience, Those are more stronger when you work with *MVVM* pattern than *MVC* pattern.